# Rails Devise Action Cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actioncable

I'm trying to get Action Cable working with Devise.

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base

    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.name
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
      if verified_user && cookies.signed['user.expires_at'] > Time.now
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If an user is logged in I still get `nil` from `cookies.signed['user.id']`

Comment: Still wondering why the official docs tell you to do it like this, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 33):

Update your `connection.rb` with the following:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.studentid
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Link:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/implementing-a-custom-devise-sign-in-and-actioncable-rails-5

Comment: What version of rails / devise / warden this is suppose to work? `env['warden'].user`  is always nil

Comment: @ArnoldRoa it contains a value only when you've already performed the authentication somewhere else before, i.e. already signed in using a classic devise form. This will set a cookie and after that, warden's rack middleware will set the `env['warden'].user` on each request.

Comment: I am having a similar issue where i have signed out and signed in and tried but the `env['warden'].user` is always nil.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the cookie in a warden callback.

Add a file to `config/initializers/your_file.rb``

Add this to the file:

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user, auth, opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = user.id
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = 60.minutes.from_now
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = nil
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = nil
end
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
verified_user = env['warden'].user
```

As explained in this very nice tuorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/

Comment: This worked well for me except that my user wasn't the default you set up with devise.  For instances that you have a different user logged in just add that user type as the next argument like so `verfied_user = env['warden'].user('admin_user')`

Comment: The right logout code:
`Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
      scope = opts[:scope]
      auth.cookies.delete("#{scope}.id")
      auth.cookies.delete("#{scope}.expires_at") 
end`

Comment: please use `auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = Devise::timeout_in.from_now` if you are using Devise