# Rails' ActionCable server-side subscribe with params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm building a REST API using Ruby on Rails as a backend. This API is consumed by a VueJS frontend. I am not using Rails' frontend, the frontend is completely independent.

I have established a WebSocket connection using ActionCable but I'm struggling to send params to the subscription.

I have the following ruby channel :

```
class WorkChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
    def subscribed
        stream_from "works-#{params[:creator_id]}"
    end
end
```

And in my JavaScript frontend, I subscribe to the channel using this code :

```
const msg = {
    command: 'subscribe',
    identifier: JSON.stringify({
        channel: 'WorkChannel',
    }),
};
socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

The subscription is successful if I remove the variable in the `stream_from` part.

On all guides and tutorials that I've read, I only found one explaining how to communicate with ActionCable without using Rails' frontend methods. See [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/talking-to-actioncable-without-rails)
for the complete guide.

However, this guide does not send data to the subscription and I can't find it on the documentation.

What is the JSON syntax of the object I need to send to emulate the behavior of `App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: 'WorkChannel', 
  creator_id: 1 }`?

I tried different syntaxes but none of them was working :

```
const msg = {
    command: 'subscribe',
    identifier: JSON.stringify({
        channel: 'WorkChannel',
    }),
    creator_id: 1,
};
```

Or

```
const msg = {
    command: 'subscribe',
    identifier: JSON.stringify({
        channel: 'WorkChannel',
        creator_id: 1,
    }),  
};
```

And even

```
const msg = {
    command: 'subscribe',
    identifier: JSON.stringify({
        channel: 'WorkChannel',
    }),
    data: {
        creator_id: 1,
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to send the user id as a parameter, it can be exploited. Imagine a user pauses the js excecution, changes the user_id and resumes, he will receive messages that goes to other users.

I'd recommend you try to get the current user id from the logged user, something like https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#server-side-components

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private
      def find_verified_user
        if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.encrypted[:user_id])
          verified_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

The correct current user detection may change depending on what authentication system you use, if you use devise, you may need to get the user from warden like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38702351/1430810

Comment: The thing is, I cannot use the logged in user because this 'user_id' parameter corresponds to the creator of the Work. And even if I use something like you showed, how can I send parameters to the subscribe method without using Rails' methods? I've seen tutorial where such a thing was accomplished but it was using `App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: 'SomeChannel', data: { some data})`. I just need to know what message is sent to the backend when using this method (because I do not have access to it in my code)

Comment: I don't know why you don't want to use the methods provided by ActionCable (why "without using Rails' methods"?). You can always use the browser's inspector's Network tab to inspect the websocket connection and see what's actually being sent when you send a message from the client to the server.

Comment: I would love to use them, it would be way easier, but the frontend is accessing the API using HTTPS. I'm not using Rails to build the frontend, neither am I using CoffeeScript or something like that. 
The frontend is completely independent and is built using Vue. 
If there is a way to access these methods in my frontend, for example with an npm package, I would gladly use them! However, I didn't find anything...

Comment: Those are not "rails" method, there's a cable.js file that you can use and you have access to them, it's just javascript. Check your /assets/javascript/ folder, cable.js should be there. Here's the official repo folder with the js files https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable/app in case you can't find them on your current project.

Comment: Oh okay I understand, I thought it was specific to Rails. If I can include this to my project, it would help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact syntax you should use:

```
{
    "command": "subscribe",
    "identifier": "{\"channel\": \"WorkChannel\", \"other_params\": \"other_stuff\",}",
    "data": 
        "{\"action\": \"some_method\", \"args\": \"{\\\"arg_1\\\": 1}\"}"
}
```

Few things to note:

- As you can see it's a JSON object (hence the `\`), normal Hash will not work.
- The channel param should be the channel class in CamelCase.
- By using the data object you can directly call some methods you defined in the channel class (with args).

---

If you are using JSON Tokens (JWT) for authentication in you Rails API, you can simply send the token in the params and access it in the connection method.

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb

module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      # here you can handle authentication using the token
      # to access the token: request.params[:user_token]
    end
  end
end
```